# Prove exponential $e^f$ is of class $C^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ a Banach space, $F=L(E,E)$ of linear and continuous functions. Define $f^0={\rm id}_E$, $f^n=f\circ\cdots\circ f$, $n$ times. Put $\exp(f)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n}{n!}$. How to show the following two points: 
>   **Added:** $f\in F$ is a linear and continuous function!
>
> 1. $\exp:F\to F$ is a function of class $C^\infty$.
> 2. $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^\infty$ from neighborhood of $0\in F$ to a 'hood of $id_E$.

**My approach:** I have already proved two facts, $\exp(f)$ is well define by proving the series converges absolutly. And $\|\exp(f)-{\rm id}_E\|<1$ if $\|f\|<\log 2$.

But the other points seems difficult: Because $\exp(f+h)-\exp(f)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(f+h)^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^n}{n!}$ and from here nothing is clear to me! I suspect the derivative would be $Dfe^{f}$. But I don't know how to prove it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Why $fe^f$? When you derivate $e^x$ you get $e^x$, not $xe^x$. 2. If $E={\mathbb R}^n$ then $f$ (and also $h$) is a square matrix, so proving via expanding $(f+h)^n$ is hard, since they do not commute.

Comment: Maybe one can try to differentiate the series term by term and then see that the resulting series converges absolutely. To calculate $Df^n$... hmmm.. maybe recursively $D(f\cdot f^{n-1})$ via derivative of a product?

Comment: I was think in $fe^f$ because, $f\in L(E,E)$ but I think I'm wrong!

Comment: Hint: The $n$-th power map $p_n: F^n\to F, f\mapsto f^n$ is differentiable, and $dp_n(f)[h]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^khf^{n-1-k}$ for all $f,h\in F$.

Comment: @Mercy can you write more detailed please, like an answer what happen is that I'm really stuck trying to understand this problem!

Comment: @LuisAlfredo Check out [here](http://wj32.org/wp/2013/02/28/frechet-derivative-of-the-matrix-exponential-function/)

Comment: Start by noticing that, for each integer $n\ge 1$, the multi-linear map
$$
B_n: F^n\to F,\quad B_n(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)=f_1\circ f_2\circ \ldots\circ f_n
$$
is differentiable, and for every $(f_1,\ldots,f_n), (h_1,\ldots,h_n) \in F$ we have
$$
dB_n(f_1,\ldots,f_n)[h_1,\ldots,h_n]=B_n(h_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)+\ldots+B_n(f_1, \ldots, f_{n-1},h_n)
$$

Comment: Using the above, you can show the $n$-th power map
$$
P_n: F\to F,\quad P_n(f)=B_n(f,\ldots,f)=f^n
$$
is also differentiable, and for all $f,h\in F$ we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
dP_n(f)[h]&=&B_n(h,f,\ldots,f)+B_n(f,h,f,\ldots,f)+\ldots+B_n(f,\ldots,f,h)\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^{k}hf^{n-k-1}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Finally, because
$$
\exp(f)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}P_n(f),
$$
it follows that $\exp$ is differentiable, and for all $f,h\in F$ we have:
$$
d\exp(f)[h]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}dP_n(f)[h]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f^khf^{n-k-1}.
$$

Comment: The second question is straightforward. In fact, $d\exp(0)[h]=h$, and you can conclude by the inverse function theorem.